# Using a BASH integer variable in an awk command

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm trying to run a command on every entry in a line of text:

```
#! /bin/bash

range=$(ls -s /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers | wc -l)

for (( i=0; i<$range; i++ ))
do  
   d=$(ls /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers | paste -sd " " | awk -F' ' '{ print $i }')
echo $d
done
```

But when I run it, it simply prints out the entire line of file entries with every iteration of the loop. I think it's because the "i" is not being interpreted since it's technically in between single quotes, and I can't figure out how to prevent it from doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Print out the numbers from 0 to $range, $range times?

Comment: I'm trying to print out every filename in a directory, range is the number of files in the directory, so I want to print out a file name $range times.

Comment: That's all? Why complicate it with `paste` and `awk`?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass variables to awk with `-v` argument like in:

```
d=$(ls /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers | paste -sd " " | awk -v var="$i" -F' ' '{ print var }')
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the names of files in a directory repeated as many times as there are files in the directory, you can use:

```
for x /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers/*; do
   ls /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers/
done
```

or

```
for x /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers/*; do
  for y /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers/*; do
    echo $x
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers/*; do echo $f; done
```